# Force finder to "refresh" an icon

Tags: macos, finder, applications, icon

Sometimes, newly-copied apps (though a bash script) end up retaining the "circle with strike-through" on top of their icon, even after running them. Restarting the system fixes this issue.

Is there any way to trigger a "refresh" of said icon, preferable *exclusively*, from the CLI? Since this is supposed to run on other systems than mine, I don't feel comfortable deleting the icon cache.

Asking in the context of OS X 10.8 and up.

[L.E.] I would also avoid relaunching Finder, if possible.

Comment: have you tried `killall Finder` ?

Comment: Well, that will be the solution, if I don't come up with something better. (Added as a later edit above, probably as you were writing.) Thanks.

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't read last sentence.. Just woke up :Z lol

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion anyway. In rare instances, killing Finder may not automatically trigger a restart. Sure, I can use `open` to relaunch it but I've just ran over a scenario under which it may fail as well. I won't get into details.

Comment: FWIW, the "touch" answer mentioned in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16543781/force-item-icon-refresh-in-finder-10-8-2 works for me - at least on Mojave.